# modprobe module error

Tags: linux-kernel

I encounterd the problem when i try to modprobe the module. this module is modified. but the module is for the kernel 2.6.33.4, also the kernel is 2.6.33.4. When i tried to modprobe module, the error happned:"disagrees about version of symbol module_layout".
i don't know how it happened and how to solve it. i'm very confused.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the address for module_layout from System.map from the /boot directory and also from the System.map generated when you compile your module. I bet it will be different. You can altogether try compiling yourself a new kernel with module versioning disabled to avoid something like this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have built your module against a kernel that is different than the running kernel into which you are attempting to insert the module.